# Bigquery how to dynamically set a query

Tags: google-bigquery

In the below query, I am getting productname, count of each item in the product and count of each customer buying the product and then calculating the percentage of customers buying the product. I am hard coding the value of the total unique customers. I want to know how i can dynamically incorporate this in my query. Joining based on purchase date is the only solution that comes to my mind. is there any other effeciante way to achive this? 
Query below

```
(SELECT ProdName, COUNT(ProdName) AS No_of_Prods, 
EXACT_COUNT_DISTINCT(cust) as No_of_cust, 
(EXACT_COUNT_DISTINCT(cust)/1500)*100 as Percentage_of_cust 
FROM 
  [Prod-cust] 
WHERE 
  (STRFTIME_UTC_USEC(Timestamp,"%Y%m%d")) = (STRFTIME_UTC_USEC(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -1, "day"), "%Y%m%d")) 
GROUP BY 
  1,
ORDER BY 
  2 DESC)
```

[image]
Query for total unique customer as below

```
(SELECT EXACT_COUNT_DISTINCT(cust), 
FROM 
  [Prod-cust]
WHERE 
  (STRFTIME_UTC_USEC(Timestamp,"%Y%m%d")) = (STRFTIME_UTC_USEC(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -1, "day"), "%Y%m%d"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    one.ProdName AS ProdName, 
    one.No_of_Prods AS No_of_Prods, 
    one.No_of_cust AS No_of_cust, 
    (one.No_of_cust/all.No_of_cust)*100 AS Percentage_of_cust 
FROM (
  SELECT 
    ProdName, 
    COUNT(ProdName) AS No_of_Prods, 
    EXACT_COUNT_DISTINCT(cust) AS No_of_cust
  FROM [Prod-cust] 
  WHERE 
    (STRFTIME_UTC_USEC(TIMESTAMP,"%Y%m%d")) = (STRFTIME_UTC_USEC(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -1, "day"), "%Y%m%d")) 
  GROUP BY 1
) AS one
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT EXACT_COUNT_DISTINCT(cust) AS No_of_cust, 
  FROM [Prod-cust] 
  WHERE 
    (STRFTIME_UTC_USEC(TIMESTAMP,"%Y%m%d")) = (STRFTIME_UTC_USEC(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -1, "day"), "%Y%m%d")
) AS all
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT number, RATIO_TO_REPORT(number) OVER() ratio
FROM (SELECT 10 number),(SELECT 40 number),(SELECT 70 number),(SELECT 20 number),(SELECT 30 number)
```

`RATIO_TO_REPORT` will add all the numbers, and give you the ratio `number/(sum number)`.

---

Updated: If we need to count the number of DISTINCT customers, then a COUNT_DISTINCT() OVER() would work as a sub-query:

```
SELECT number, number/distincts ratio
FROM (
  SELECT number, COUNT_DISTINCT(id) OVER() distincts 
  FROM (SELECT 10 number, 1 id),(SELECT 30 number, 2 id),
       (SELECT 60 number, 3 id),(SELECT 20 number, 1 id),
       (SELECT 40 number, 1 id)
)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, It doesn't work here because of distinct numbers

Comment: oh.. from the original query

Comment: Yes, non-additive metrics. I think Ratio_to_report type of function will work perfectly with additive metrics like page counts for example, but not with non-additive, like unique users for example